# Pattern for defining defaults arguments without duplication and keeping prototype

Tags: python, decorator, default-value

I've noticed that I regularly have the following pattern:

- A class that on instantiation sets default values
- A function that allows one to change some of these default values

A simple example that works is the following:

```py
class A:
  defaults = dict(x=10, y=100)
  def __init__(self):
    self.params = A.defaults
  def set(self, **kwargs):
    self.params.update(kwargs)
```

However, the set function does not have the desired prototype: one can call a.set(z=20) without any errors. Furthermore, this prevents correct hovering information for the IDE and correct return values by the inspect module.

Ideally, we would want something like this (not valid python):

```py
class A:
  defaults = dict(x=10, y=100)
  def __init__(self):
    self.params = A.defaults
  def set(self, **{k:None for k in A.defaults.keys()}):
    self.params.update({k:v for k,v in kwargs.items() if not k is None})
```

With **{k:None for k in A.defaults.keys()} evaluated at function definition (not possible to my knowledge). This would allow correct error information to be displayed, as well as correct hovering information in IDE, and correct information for the inspect module.

I feel this is a pattern that occurs quite often, probably also in major packages such as numpy, pandas, ... and I was wondering how this situation was handled...

Of course, one solution is to directly write the set function with that prototype oneself. But that means we kind of have code duplication and then need to keep the defaults dictionary and the parameters of set in sync. This not an ideal solution...

I already tried writing a decorator for the first version, and raise an error in it if the parameters in kwargs are not keys of defaults. However, this does not solve the actual prototype of the function which the IDE uses for hovering information, but may also be used for other purposes though the use of the inspect module.

**Bonus**: If there is anyway to handle type annotations such that when defaults is defined as
 `defaults : Dict[str, int] = dict(x=10, y=100)`, the type annotations of set are int.

**Bonus2**: what if the different arguments have different types?